# i want to make vr games in unity using google cardboard vr package, but it need old version of android SDK Manager to buid

Tags: unity-game-engine, virtual-reality, android-sdk-manager

[a screenshot from developer.android.com](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u6cdM.png)
im making a vr project in unity, but the vr unity package i use need an old version SDK Manager (only SDK Manager, not the build-tools), i've search in trough the internet but i can't find it, even in the official release page only the most recent version available. Please help me, i need it to finish my project so i can graduate college

I've search it all over the internet, even ask chatGPT to help me but it always lead me to developer.android.com, i need SDK Manager version late 2019 or older

If any of you have that version or know where to find, please tell me

Comment: Does this help? https://developer.android.com/studio/archive

Answer (score 0):

You can use the SDK manager of the Unity 2019 lts version. [Unity Archive](https://unity.com/releases/editor/archive) has all the previous lts versions. Then change the SDK and JDK of your current editor to the SDK and JDK of Unity 2019 from the Edit->prefernce->External tools. Hope this helps